# How to initialize a processor via NIFI API

Tags: apache-nifi

please help!

I'm using ListSFTP processor to get files and process them. In the first execution the processor take the files normally, but when you start the processor the second time it doesn't. I know this is the correct behavior for this processor. Is there any way to start and initialize the processor via NIFI API in such a way that It takes the files again? I need this approach because I need to do testing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is expected behavior (otherwise on every "list" operation, the processor would return the same list of files). In order to use this for testing, you can right click on the stopped processor and choose **View State** and then click **Clear** in the dialog that is presented. The next time the processor runs, it will list all files present (and matching the appropriate filter patterns) again. Those actions are also available via the [REST API](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/rest-api/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

http://localhost:8081/nifi-api/processors/{id_processor}/state/clear-requests

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know of a Java library which could be used to generate this reqest?